# Redirect from http to https not working

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, https, redirection

I installed certbot on my debian to install lets encrypt certificate to apache2.
Everything worked like a charm, and I selected the software option to redirect http traffic to https.

The software changed my apache2 conf file in this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myweburl.com
    ServerAlias www.myweburl.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweburl/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/myweburl>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All
            ReWriteEngine On
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

/////////
// The software added these lines
/////////
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myweburl.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.myweburl.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

These lines don't work.
If I visit myweburl.com it does not redirect.
If I visit https:// www.myweburl.com I can see the correct installed certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current versions of Apache, there are potentially several ways to approach this:

- Try using `%{HTTP_HOST}` rather than `%{SERVER_NAME}`

*ex. Using `%HTTP_HOST`*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myweburl.com
    ServerAlias www.myweburl.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweburl/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/myweburl>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myweburl.com [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.myweburl.com
            # RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
            RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

- Using `Redirect`. This requires that [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) be enabled.

*ex. Using `Redirect`*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myweburl.com
    ServerAlias www.myweburl.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    # DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweburl/public

    Redirect permanent / https://myweburl.com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

- Use alternative `Rewrite` rules. [You can read more about mod_rewrite remapping here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).

*ex. Alternate `mod_rewrite` rules*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myweburl.com
    ServerAlias www.myweburl.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweburl/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/myweburl>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
            # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you guided me to the solution. My problem was I forgot to add `RewriteEngine on` line on apache conf file. I thought it was enabled by default.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it solved =).